# How to use regex to capture text inside of a given set of characters

Tags: regex, regex-group

For example this regular expression will capture everything inside of curly braces: {[^}]+} so in this string "Hello how {are} you?" the word "are" will be captured.

Similarly, this captures everything in square brackets: [(.*?)]

I don't understand the similarity between the two and can't figure out how to capture text inside other identifiers. For example, what if I wanted to capture everything inside of characters like this:
^{this}^ in which I want everything inside of ^{ }^ or like this #[ ]#.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for following regex

```
.*(?:\[|\{)(.*?)(?=\]|\}).*
```

Then you need to consider Group 1.

(?:) to Non-capturing groups and drop them from the result. Defining both { and [ so that these will not be captured.

X(?=Y)  Positive lookahead  X if followed by Y